# Definite article, italics/quotations for a document name?

Tags: capitalization, definite-articles, quotation-marks, italics

The below text is an extract from a document titled Technical Specification 13 Meter Harbor Tug.

1. Is it sufficient to have the title capitalized or do I need to put it into italics/quotes when referencing the same?
2. Should I use the definite article in heading 000.a) or it is ok without it if immediately below I will define the term Technical Specification?
3. If 2. is ok, can I omit "This Technical Specification"
4. If 3. can be omitted, what happens if Technical Specification Some Other Ship is mentioned elsewhere in the document? I feel like this requires the "This Technical Specification" or a rewording of heading 000.a)

> **000 INTRODUCTION**
>
> **000.a) Intent of Technical Specification**
>
> **This Technical Specification, Technical Specification 13 Meter Harbor Tug, beside the Contract, is the most important contractual document.**

Comment: Yes, title okay. No need for article in the title. Remove duplication or you're not editing.

Comment: Legally, "the contract" contains all the documents which evidence the agreement, not just the one with the signatures and the _testamentum_ clause.  Your lawyer will be able to advise you on the most appropriate names for the documents in question, but it's unlikely that "The Contract" will be one of them.

Comment: Thank You for Your inputs. I've added question 4

Comment: Like all publishers, in- or external, your organisation should have a clear protocol handling every such query.

If there is none then the first responsibility of anyone in a position like yours should be to establish it.

Please go up your chain of management until you reach someone with both experience and authority in both your department's technical content, and the organisation's publishing protocols.

If there is no such person, complain to your own manager and preferably to everyone up to and including the directors responsible for both your own department, and publishing.

Comment: Thanks Robbie, much appreciated input!